# How to initialize a module in python 3.x so that it can be imported?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In 
**Python 2.7** I'd do

```
void InitPython()
{
    ..
    Py_InitModule3("my_prog", ProgMethods, "documentation");
    ..
}
```

Then I will simply be able to do `import my_prog` like this in my [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code

```
char strCode[] = "import my_prog, sys, os\n"
```

[PyRun_SimpleString](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleString)(strCode);

---

However in
**Python 3.6**, following the official documentation and applying the changes doesn't work

```
static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "my_prog",                          /* m_name */
    "documentation",                    /* m_doc */
    -1,                                 /* m_size */
    ProgMethods,                        /* m_methods */
    NULL,                               /* m_reload */
    NULL,                               /* m_traverse */
    NULL,                               /* m_clear */
    NULL,                               /* m_free */
};

void InitPython()
{
    ..
    PyObject *m1 = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
    ..
}
```

Fails with following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_prog'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation I can find](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function) says your initialization function should be named `PyInit_mymodule` and marked with `PyMODINIT_FUNC`:

```py
static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    // ...
    {"system",  spam_system, METH_VARARGS, "Execute a shell command."},
    // ...
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

// ...

static struct PyModuleDef spammodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "spam",
    spam_doc,
    -1,
    SpamMethods
};

// ...

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_spam(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&spammodule);
}
```

(As an aside, unless you really do need to create your extension in C, I'd recommend looking at [Cython](https://cython.org/) too.)